# mySQL add prefix

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a homework. With phpAdmin myAQL, I created a database as "odk", and I have 6 tables. I created them with no problem.

My teacher said

> Save each query with the table name and prefix. (Ex: Employeeqry, departmentqry). DO not use the same name as tables for the query names.

and I use

```
SELECT Concat('ALTER TABLE ', employee, ' RENAME TO qry', employee, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<odk>';
```

It worked, but I cannot see any prefix. Can you help me?

**homework**

```
1- Create a database with your name,
2- Create tables of Company miniworld using "CREATE TABLE" statements in your book page 181 (7th edition)
3- Run each create query and examine the created table.
4- Save each query with the table name and prefix. (Ex: Employeeqry, departmentqry). DO not use the same name as tables for the query names.
```

**mysql (odk)**

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Anamakine: 127.0.0.1
-- Üretim Zamanı: 30 Mar 2020, 15:04:49
-- Sunucu sürümü: 10.4.11-MariaDB
-- PHP Sürümü: 7.4.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Veritabanı: `odk`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `department`
--

CREATE TABLE `department` (
  `Dname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Dnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Mgr_ssn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Mgr_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `dependent`
--

CREATE TABLE `dependent` (
  `Essn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Dependent_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Relationship` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `dept_locations`
--

CREATE TABLE `dept_locations` (
  `Dnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Dlocation` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `employee`
--

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `Fname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Minit` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Lname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Ssn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Bdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Sex` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Super_ssn` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dno` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `project`
--

CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `Pname` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `Pnumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Plocation` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dnum` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tablo için tablo yapısı `works_on`
--

CREATE TABLE `works_on` (
  `Essn` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Pno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Hours` decimal(3,1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dökümü yapılmış tablolar için indeksler
--

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `department`
--
ALTER TABLE `department`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Dnumber`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Dname` (`Dname`),
  ADD KEY `Mgr_ssn` (`Mgr_ssn`);

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `dependent`
--
ALTER TABLE `dependent`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Essn`,`Dependent_name`);

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `dept_locations`
--
ALTER TABLE `dept_locations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Dnumber`,`Dlocation`);

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `employee`
--
ALTER TABLE `employee`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Ssn`);

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `project`
--
ALTER TABLE `project`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Pnumber`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Pname` (`Pname`),
  ADD KEY `Dnum` (`Dnum`);

--
-- Tablo için indeksler `works_on`
--
ALTER TABLE `works_on`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Essn`,`Pno`),
  ADD KEY `Pno` (`Pno`);

--
-- Dökümü yapılmış tablolar için kısıtlamalar
--

--
-- Tablo kısıtlamaları `department`
--
ALTER TABLE `department`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `department_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Mgr_ssn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`Ssn`);

--
-- Tablo kısıtlamaları `dependent`
--
ALTER TABLE `dependent`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dependent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Essn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`Ssn`);

--
-- Tablo kısıtlamaları `dept_locations`
--
ALTER TABLE `dept_locations`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dept_locations_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Dnumber`) REFERENCES `department` (`Dnumber`);

--
-- Tablo kısıtlamaları `project`
--
ALTER TABLE `project`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `project_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Dnum`) REFERENCES `department` (`Dnumber`);

--
-- Tablo kısıtlamaları `works_on`
--
ALTER TABLE `works_on`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `works_on_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Essn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`Ssn`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `works_on_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Pno`) REFERENCES `project` (`Pnumber`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: That's rather a post-fix,

Comment: I don't know what's being asked for by your tutor unless he/she wants you to include code to rename the tables you just created but even at that he/she is not asking for that code to be submitted.

Comment: @P.Salmon he wants to receive our odk.sql formatted files. I do not know why he want rename it.

Comment: You need to use the name of the table which is dynamically built from the name of source table adding a postfix `qry` - this can be performed using dynamic SQL only (prepared statement) in stored procedure.

Comment: I think your teacher wants you to save each query to a separate file.

Comment: yes every creatr table in his own sql file qith create_department.sql for department and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your teacher means by query, but I bet he means to create a View.

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW qryTable AS
SELECT * FROM myTable;
```